# Check if list is Ascending OR Descending (using FOR)

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop

So I have been set a task in my college where I'm suppose to check whether a list is in fact sorted (either ascending or descending). But I MUST use 'for'. (We just recently learned about for and lists and we must practice it)

This is what I have so far, I am able to confirm if a list is descending, but not descending OR ascending:

```
A=[10,9,8,3,1,0]

def order(A):
    for i in range(len(A) - 1): 
        if ((A[i]>A[i+1])) :
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to return whether the list is ascending, descending, or neither.

```
def order(A):
if A == sorted(A,reverse=False):
    return 'Ascending'
elif A == sorted(A,reverse=True):
    return 'Descending'
else:
    return 'Neither'
```

Here is a sample output with simple input.

```
>> a = [2,5,4,7,1]
>> b = [1,3,5,7,9]
>> c = [9,6,3,1,0]
>> print(order(a), order(b), order(c))
out: Neither Ascending Descending
```

The benefit of this function is that we don't have to analyze the individual elements, we simply have to use built-in functions to analyze the list as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an algorithm in a such way so that the result before the other parameter, is unique!

For ascending, check if the subtraction between the current item and the next time is greater than 0, if so, it is not sorted ascending.

For descending, check if the subtraction between the current item and the next time is lesser than 0, if so, it is not sorted descending.

Try this:

```
def order(A) # Ascending order
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        if A[i] - A[i+1] > 0:
            return False
    return True

def order(A) # Descending order
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        if A[i] - A[i+1] < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
A=[10,9,8,3,1,0]
B=[1,9,18,33,41,50]
C=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
D= [1]
E=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
F =[]

def order(someList):
    asc = True
    desc = True

    for idx in range(1, len(someList)):
        if someList[idx] - someList[idx - 1] >= 0:
            asc = asc & True
            desc = desc & False
        else:
            desc = desc & True
            asc = asc & False

    if asc and not desc:
        return "list is in ascending order"
    elif desc and not asc:
        return "list is in descending order"
    else:
        return "list is in no order"

print(order(A))
print(order(B))
print(order(C))
print(order(D))
print(order(E))
print(order(F))
```

and when executed, this code's output was:

```
list is in descending order
list is in ascending order
list is in ascending order
list is in no order
list is in no order
list is in no order
```

Here what we are doing is that we are maintaining two boolean flags `asc` and `desc`, which will represent whether the list passed was in ascending order or descending order.

Then for each consecutive pair of numbers in the list, we calculate their difference `if someList[idx] - someList[idx - 1] >= 0:` then we and `desc` flag with `False` and vice versa in the `else` case.

Intuitively, what is being done in this code is as follows:
if a sequence is in ascending order, then every consecutive pair of numbers will have their difference greater than zero, for ex: consider this sequence `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` where all characters represent numbers and assume for the case when this sequence is in ascending order i.e `a <= b <= c <= d <= e <= f` and if we consider all the consecutive pairs of numbers i.e `(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), and so on..` and calculate difference for each of those pairs i.e `b-a, c-b, d-c and so on..` then `every difference will be >= 0` i.e `b-a >= 0 and c-b >= 0 and d-c >= 0 and e-d >= 0 and f-e >= 0` and this is the condition that is being represented by the `asc` boolean flag in the code above. Similar explanation can be thought for `desc` boolean flag.

And if you want a **smaller version** of the code above **while still using `for` loop** then use this:

```
A=[10,9,8,3,1,0]
B=[1,9,18,33,41,50]
C=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
D= [1]
E=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
F = []

def order(someList):

    results = [True if second >= first else False for first, second in zip(someList, someList[1:])]

    if any(results) and all(results):
        return "ascending order"
    elif not any(results) and not all(results):
        return "descending order"
    else:
        return "no order"

print(order(A))
print(order(B))
print(order(C))
print(order(D))
print(order(E))
print(order(F))
```

and output for this

```
descending order
ascending order
ascending order
no order
no order
no order
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return `True` if the `list` is `ascending` **or** `descending`.

This makes the `code` really *readable**:

```
def order(lst):
    ascending = descending = True
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1): 
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1] :
            ascending = False
        elif lst[i] < lst[i+1] :
            descending = False
    return ascending or descending
```

We start by defining `2` `boolean` `variables` set to `True` - `ascending` and `descending`. We then loop through the `lst` (I gave the `function` a more sensible `param` name) and check `if` this `index` is less than the next. If it is, we can set the `ascending` `variable` to `False` (as the `lst` can now no longer be `ascending). Else, if the next index is greater than the current`index`, we set`descending`to`False`.

Then finally, at the end we `return` if either the `lst` was `ascending` **`or`** `descending`.

---

Some examples:

```
>>> order([1,2,3,4])
True
>>> order([1,2,3,2])
False
>>> order([3,2,1,0])
True
>>> order([3,2,1,4])
False
```

Hope this helps! (by the way, if your interested, you could literally do the same `function` in `one-line`):

```
def order(lst):
    return lst == sorted(lst) or lst == sorted(lst)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def descending(l):
  x=0
  if len(l)<= 1 or (len(l) == 2 and l[0] >= l[1]):
    return True
  else:
    if l[0]<=l[1]:
      return descending(l[1:])
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: don't just post a code without little explanation.You also need to learn more about formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help